# how to set the value of a dropdown to its default always

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

A Page has Repeater Control displays students records, when click on any record it displays total info, this page has a dropdownlist and other controls contained in panel set to visible false.     When the user search it displays the students info [ 10 rows ]
 it displays SSN, FName, LName,DOB  when he wants to see the more detail description of the student he clicks on that student row , then we make panel to be visible
it has a dropdown and set its dataTextfield to all the departments from the database. Here i want to display the dropdown to its default "Select deptartment"  he selects any dept and clicks "SAVE" then page reloads and it again it should set to its default value "Select deptartment"....this one i am unable to do this

i did this way      `dd.items,insert(0,"Select deptartment").....`> with this each time page reloads this item is added to dropdown
  and i tried

```
dd.selectedindex= 0
```

as the data items are coming from database..we cannot set the value to its default.

Answer (score 0):

In the DataBound event of your dropdownlist can't you just use the dd.selectedValue = TheValue where TheValue is the string value you gave to the "Select Department" item when you added it to the DDL?

Comment: i did that way but the default is not set to "select department" every a new item is added to dd with select department

Comment: In that case what I would try is this: In the DataBound method of the dropdownlist, loop through the items collection until you find the item with the "Select Department" text, store its index in a variable and then set the selectedindex.
If that does not work then I don't know what else either...

Comment: Just a thought... Maybe it would work if you tried to set the value later than the databound event if that is what is causing the problem, like say in the unload event of your control?

Comment: my code islike  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_name" runat="server" DataSourceID="Employee" DataMember="Technical"
                                        DataTextField="Last_name" 
                                        DataValueField="Emp_code"
                                        FirstItemText="Select Item" 
                                        FirstItemValue="0"
                                        BoundColumnName="LastName"
                                        BoundDataMember="DeptCode"
                                        Clear="true"
                                        />

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code it will work,

```
            Conn.Open()
            dr= cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            dd.DataSource = dr
            dd.DataValueField = "ColumnName"
            dd.DataBind()
            dd.Items.Insert(0, "-----Select department-----")
            Conn.Close()
```

Comment: I wrote in databound event  .items.inser(0,"--select dept")       dd.selectedindex= 0, this way i can see the default to select dept but each time i refresh the page new select dept is added to the dropdown

Comment: when u bind for every time u clear the items, before adding to the Dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dd" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="133px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dd_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">[Select]</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>

dd.SelectedIndex = 0;
```